# Best way to save code snippets when using QT and SQLite

Tags: qt, sqlite, qt-creator, code-snippets

I am running linux/Ubuntu and have been disaponted with the quality of code snippet managers. None work for how/what I like so I am building my own basic version. I am doing this also for the coding practice.

So I am going to use QT5 and SQLite to run an in application database. From my previous experience with databases if you want to save 2 or 3 pages of text you usally don't want to save it directly to the database. You want to have the text in a file or something else and then have a link or file location stored in the database so it points to the text.

If I go that route should I have a separate file for each code snippet. Seems overkill. Maybe I should have some set maximum file size and as code snippets get added you create a new file and begin to add to that one. If I do that I think I would need to have and offset stored in the DB so it can quickly get to the wanted code snippet.

Are there any other architectural ideas for how to store the code so that it would scale if someone had a lot of different code snippets with some of those code snippets being very large? Are there other considerations I should be aware of?

Comment: Your previous experience is wrong; SQLite (or any other database) can handle 2–3-page text snippets just fine

Comment: From my experience when wanting to save an image, even a small icon, you want to save the file location and not the file itself into the database. What documentation or otherwise do you now that explains the understanding that you have?

Comment: And *why* would you want to do that? Why duplicate all the data management that the database already does for you? Rumors that files are faster [are mostly wrong](https://www.sqlite.org/intern-v-extern-blob.html).